# Select/Deselect optgroup based on option select in select picker Boostrap

Tags: bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to select option group based on option select.
Option Group name is Class and class has two option (Class A , Class B).
If i select Class A, Class B then automatically Option Group selected. suppose if i deselected Class A then Option Group is deselected.

I want to do with select picker of bootstrap functionality.

[image]

I have tried but not got any hint. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to write your own custom javascript event + function to handle this behavior. It is not supported out of the box by bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks dommmm. Can you give reference link or some examples. so i can go over there. I am too much tried.

Comment: it's basic javascript. i'll give you the rough outline of what needs to be done:

`when (event triggered) {

        if (condition met) {

        do thisFunction();

        }

    }`

Comment: I have apply onchange event, but it's not working for me.

Comment: update your question with the code you wrote so we can help

Answer (score 4):

I have added the following line to the bootstrap-select.js in my project to allow this functionality: find **clickListener: function() {** and insert

it will work when you click on the group title

```
this.$newElement.find('li').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Bootstrap-Select.js - line #1438');
      var base = $(this).closest(".bootstrap-select");
      var select = base.find("select");

      // check if this .dropdown-header is part of bootstrap-select AND multiple or not
      if (base.length && select.prop("multiple")) {

          var group = $(this).data("optgroup") - 1;
          var group2 = group + 1;
          var select = $(this).closest(".bootstrap-select").find("select");

          if ($(this).hasClass("dropdown-header")) {

              if (base.find("li[data-optgroup=" + group2 + "]:not(.selected)").length === 1)
                  $(this).closest(".bootstrap-select").find("select > optgroup:eq(" + group + ") > option").prop("selected", false);
              else
                  $(this).closest(".bootstrap-select").find("select > optgroup:eq(" + group + ") > option").prop("selected", true);

              select.selectpicker('render');
              //select.change();
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: This my friend was the ONLY solution that has worked for me after hours of trying other solutions!! I inserted it at line 1435! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked straight away when I implemented this solution 

Comment: I made solution for boostrap4: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/737#issuecomment-686415322